# PHP SoapServer, how can I access my entity manager from within the class?

Tags: php, doctrine, soapserver

I have a SoapServer. This soap server has a class

```php
$server = new \SoapServer($this->wsdl_path, array('classmap' => $this->classmap));
$server->setClass('MyNamespace\\MyBundle\\Lib\\MySoapMethods');
```

And I have the class MySoapMethods which actually contain the methods being executed.

```php
class MySoapMethods
{
  public function sendNotification(NotificationRequest $request) {}
}
```

The call being made is sendNotification. My question is: How can I inject my EntityManager of Doctrine in here? I can't find any method for this and I really hate using static calls for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.setclass.php

You can specify more arguments to the setServer method which will be passed to the constructor of the called class.